# Eclipse no longer opens, and it gives me the following error:

Tags: java, eclipse

Error below. Does anyone know why this is happening?

> An error has occurred. See the log file /Users/Christian/Dropbox/Projects/Java Projects/.metadata/.log.

Log file:

(Was too big to post on SO, so here it is on gist:)

https://gist.github.com/4122659

Comment: Go you have the right SWT dependencies in your class path for your environment?

Comment: Your name is Doug, but it's using Christian's Dropbox. Maybe you don't have permissions on it. Unless you are a Christian who names his username after his religion.

Comment: @Bohemian Because everyone uses the same user name on every online account they own?

Comment: Sorry, typo the comment is do you have the right swt dependencies on your classpath. The other thing, is your workspace could be corrupt does the same issue happen when you try opening a new workspace?

Comment: If I had to guess, you have an Eclipse workspace in Dropbox, and you use or share that workspace with multiple people (or yourself). The problem is workspaces are not ment to be shared. [Ref this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8445618/504685). Create a new workspace unique to an individual machine. You can still share projects in dropbox, although you might consider a proper scm like [github](https://github.com/).

Comment: I would create a new workspace, but it won't even open.

Comment: Try using `eclipse -clean` as mentioned [in this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413427/504685)

Comment: The -data switch will tell it to use a different workspace location, e.g. eclipse.exe -data d:\workspace2