# Same workspace with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink

I'm using Eclipse in server and I have two users who can connect on this server. I want to find a solution which allows me to use the same workspace by they two users. I tried it and I got an error message which tells me that you can't use this workspace because it is used by another user and it makes sense. But I want to know if they have a solution which allows me to open the same workspace in the same time by the differents users who use the different authority.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445522/sharing-a-workspace-for-many-developers-in-eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that as it locks the workspace for one user. others cant edit the same. Try using Version Control like Git or SVN.

Answer (score 0):

You can make developers use the same Eclipse by starting it's launcher with the "-data" argument set to a unique folder. (Let's say the user's name)

You can write a startup-script that copies the contents of a reference workspace, each time a user starts using this shared Eclipse.

But that's the most you can achieve; two instances of Eclipse can not use the same workspace. In server terms: think of it as a Session rather than a Workspace.